# Why is my list not being updated in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state, kotlin-flow

I have a ViewModel which contains a StateFlow which is being collected on the main screen. The first method I use in my viewModel is to get it to check if there are elements in the database and if not, request them from the API and save them in the database. This works correctly.

The first problem I encountered was that apparently, if the list I send it is exactly the same, it doesn't execute the method to do the recomposition of my view, so I had to make a copy of the element I wanted to change and modify it this way.

The problem I have right now is that when I have made my new list, before I make the .value to my StateFlow, the list is already updated with the latest data, but I haven't told it to do it at any time. I suspect that it has something to do with the collectAsState that I have in the view, since I don't know very well how it works inside, and that's why I'm asking for your help. Here is the code I've been talking about:

```kotlin
// This class corresponds to my ViewModel

class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val monumentsState = MutableStateFlow<List<MonumentVo>>(emptyList())
    fun getMonumentsLiveData(): StateFlow<List<MonumentVo>> = monumentsState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        getMonuments()
    }

    private fun getMonuments() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            GetAllMonumentsFromLocalUseCase().map { it.toVo() }.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
                ?.apply {
                    monumentsState.value = this
                    Log.d("Estado monumentos", "${monumentsState.value}")
                } ?: run {
                val monumentsFromRemote = GetAllMonumentsFromRemoteUseCase().monuments

                InsertMonumentsToDatabaseUseCase().insertAllMonumentsToDatabase(
                    monuments = monumentsFromRemote.map { it.toVo() }
                )
                monumentsState.value =
                    GetAllMonumentsFromLocalUseCase().map { it.toVo() }
                Log.d("Estado monumentos", "${monumentsState.value}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun setMonumentFavorite(monument: MonumentVo) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            InsertMonumentFavoriteUseCase().insertMonumentFavorite(monument)

            val updatedMonuments = GetAllMonumentsFromLocalUseCase().map {
                if (it.title == monument.title) {
                    it.copy(isFavorite = it.isFavorite)
                } else {
                    it
                }.toVo()
            }
            Log.d("Estado monumentos", "${monumentsState.value}")
            Log.d("Estado monumentos", "$updatedMonuments")
            monumentsState.value = updatedMonuments
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

```kotlin
// This is my composable view

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
    navigateToDetail: (String) -> Unit
) {

    val monuments by homeViewModel.getMonumentsLiveData().collectAsState()

    Screen {

        if (monuments.isEmpty()) {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }

        } else {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                items(monuments) { monument ->
                    Card(
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                            containerColor = LightGray
                        ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 5.dp)
                            .clickable { navigateToDetail(monument.title) }
                    ) {
                        MonumentRow(monument, homeViewModel)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think multiple things are going wrong, but it works for me if you remove Dispatchers.IO and use this kind of pattern (I used String instead of your MonumentVo class and simplified the calls a bit while testing for simplicity):

```kotlin
    private val _monumentsState = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
    val monumentsState: StateFlow<List<String>> by lazy {
        getMonuments()
        _monumentsState
    }

    private fun getMonuments() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val someNewStrings = listOf("Eiffel tower", "Louvre")
            _monumentsState.value = someNewStrings
        }
    }

    fun setMonumentFavorite(monument: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _monumentsState.value = monumentsState.value + monument
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `SnapshotStateList`

```
val data =  SnapshotStateList< MonumentVo >()
fun addDataToList(monumentVo: MonumentVo) {
     data.add(monumentVo)
 }
```

I was facing the same problem, this helped me. More details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList)